# Why read.delim() cannot open text files?

Tags: r, data-import

I have saved an Excel file as Tab delimited, but when I try to open it I get the following error:

```
a=read.delim("GBM tab")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'GBM tab': No such file or directory
```

While I have a text file named GBM tab in my working directory.
Even when I press Tab, no matches are found. What is the problem?

Comment: please check the file name.  should it have `GBT.txt`

Comment: You perhaps have the wrong working directory. `list.files()` will list the names of all the files in the current working directory. Does the name you are entering match one of thise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easier option is to use `file.choose()` and then just direct to the file in the directory

```
a <- read.delim(file.choose())
```

In the OP's code, it is possible that a file have `.txt` or `.csv` at the end it needs to be specified

```
a <- read.delim("GBM tab.txt")
```